# A CSS rule for elements with particular class affects only the first instance

Tags: html, css, frontend

When I applied relative positioning to "div" elements with the class value "questions", it only affected the first "div" element with the "question" class. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="question">
    <h4>Question 1</h4>
    <h2>I like participating in physical activity such as running, swimming, or biking.</h2>
</div>

  <div class="question">
    <h4>Question 2</h4>
    <h2>I try to keep up to date with the latest fashion in active wear.</h2>
</div>

 <div class="question">
    <h4>Question 3</h4>
    <h2>I purchase clothing online regularly.</h2>
 </div>

 <div class="question">
    <h4>Question 4</h4>
    <h2>I try to buy goods that are designed and/or manufactured in my home country.</h2>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.question {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code words fine for me as posted.

If I embed your css into the html index like...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css_01.css">
</head>
<body>
...
```

I get the output expected. I can confirm that by adding extra mods to the selector like font color:

```
.question {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    color: pink;
    /* as a test */
  }
```

Perhaps your real code is more complex than posted. Check the browser javascript console for errors that may be interrupting the formatting of all the headings.